How to implement BreadcrumbView with dynamic components?
I'm in need of a breadcrumb like view that manages the dynamic components added to it.  For example, what I currently have kind of starting to work is I've created a BreadcrumbWithComponents functional component.  It starts out rendering the 1st component.  Depending on what the user clicks on in that 1st component, I need to dynamically add a new component to the parent BreadcrumbWithComponents component, update the breadcrumb bar, HIDE the 1st component (display:none), and let it render the dynamically added 2nd component.
To achieve the above:

The 1st component in the click event is able to create a variable with JSX containing the new component to add.  This component is importing any other components that it could possibly lead too.
The 1st component calls a callback that is handled by BreadcrumbWithComponents  which adds the passed JSX to a components collection which is stored in state (Yes, I know, I've now read that I shouldn't be storing jsx in state). The state managed activeIndex is incremented.
BreadcrumbWithComponents  render function renders the {components}
Problem is the 1st component is still visible and the 2nd component is rendered beneath it.  The css with the conditional display tied to activeIndex isn't being recalculated to 'none'.

I've since read a lot of stuff but can't find a good example of how to achieve what I want.  Whenever somebody asks about storing jsx in state, the advice is always the same, don't do it, store some simple data in an array and then rerender the data.  The problem is their examples always assume the array is going to render the exact same components or that it's hardcoded with elements to create.
In my case, I don't know what components to render in the array.  The BreadcrumbWithComponents  doesn't know about them.  I don't want to import every single eventual component in my app into BreadcrumbWithComponents. I don't want to have a massive if statement checking for what type of component to render. I do like how currently whatever the current step component is, which does import any components that it can possibly lead to, is able to create the jsx and send it to be added to BreadcrumbWithComponents.
How would one implement a control that needs to track an array of components that are not know ahead of time and are dynamically added as the user navigates and also it needs to keep track of them all, display a breadcrumb trail for each dynamically added one and only ever display the last one. But they all need to stay loaded (at least their data does).
For example, the 1st step is a list.  The user clicks a row in that list.  The next dynamically added component is an edit form for that list item.  That edit form has next and previous navigation buttons that needs to be able to access the list of data from the previous breadcrumb step to update it's id to render the next/previous record. The edit screen has a back button that the user can click (or they can click on the 1st breadcrumb step) and then the 2nd component is destroyed and it goes back to rendering the 1st step with the list.
UPDATE:
The main application shell is based on react-router-tabs . I want my users to be able to work on multiple things at once and I want routes to open as new material tabs, not browser tabs.
The user clicks a left nav menu that launches /products.  This causes a new material tab to be displayed.  The first component in that tab is the BreadcrumbForms component below.  The route points to ProductList component which ends up being rendered inside the outlet of the first breadcrumb step.  Then inside the ProductList component I am using AgGrid.  The user can click a product in the grid which causes a callback back to the parent
BreadcrumbForms to launch the ProductEdit component as the next step in the breadcrumb trail. At this point, the 1st step ProductList should be hidden.  The ProductEdit component will eventually have next/previous buttons and I will need to then solve how to ask back to the ProductList component what the next/previous product id is.


const BreadcrumbCallbackContext = createContext({
  openForm: (formName: string,jsx: JSX.Element) => { } // Default callback function
});

export const breadcrumbContext = () => useContext(BreadcrumbCallbackContext);

export function BreadcrumbForms() {

  const [activeBreadcrumbIndex, setactiveBreadcrumbIndex] = useState(0);

  // this callback is used by child components to add new 'steps'
  // to the breadcrumb
  const handleCallback = (formName: string, jsx: JSX.Element) => {
    console.log('Callback triggered from component child in breadcrumb');

    // doesn't work as the component (formName) is not imported here
    // so switched to the child component that does know about it generated jsx
    // to pass here
    //const html = '<' + formName + '/>';
    //const jsx = <div>{parse(html)}</div>;

    // add new component
    components.push(jsx);
    setComponents(components);
    setactiveBreadcrumbIndex(1);
  };

  const firstStepStyles = ({ activeBreadcrumbIndex }: { activeBreadcrumbIndex: number }) => css`
    display:${activeBreadcrumbIndex == 0 ? "content" : "none"};
    height:100%;  
  `;

  // we get here via routing. The parent tab is created and this breaccrumb component
  // is the 1st component in the tab, and now the outlet will render the component
  // attached to the route.  From then on, no more routing.  We will rely on user events
  // from clicks, etc to launch the next 'steps'
  const [components, setComponents] = useState(
    [
      <div css={firstStepStyles({ activeBreadcrumbIndex }) }>
        <BreadcrumbCallbackContext.Provider value={{ openForm: handleCallback }}>
            <Outlet context={{ callback: handleCallback }} />
        </BreadcrumbCallbackContext.Provider>
      </div>
    ]);
  
  return (
    <div style={{ height: '100%' }}>
      {components}
    </div>
  );

}




// a component rendered as the 1st step inside the breadcrumb
export function ProductList() {

  const { openForm } = breadcrumbContext();

  const onOpenForm = (formName: string) => {

    //const html = '<' + formName + '/>';
    //const jsx = <div>{parse(html)}</div>;
    const jsx = <div><ProductEdit /></div>;

    //const component = lazy(() => import('../product_edit/product_edit'));
    openForm("ProductEdit", jsx);

    return;
  }

  // grid stuff
  ....
  
  return (
    <SearchInterface title="Product List!" colDefs={colDefs} onOpenForm={onOpenForm}>
      <SearchInterface.Grid>
        Grid Control       
      </SearchInterface.Grid>
    </SearchInterface>
  );

}


// product list would launch this as the next component in the breadcrumb after the user selects a grid row
export function ProductEdit() {
  return (
    <p>Product Edit form</p>
  );
}



Current Issues:

I've read not to use state to store JSX
The 1st component is not hiding. It seems like it's not regenerating. The 2nd component is rendering beneath the 1st
If the user switches from the top level tab Products to another tab like Customers and then back to Products, only the 1st component is rendered.  The 2nd component is no longer beneath the 1st component.


Could you provide a minimal working example so I could suggest any code improvements?
For now, there is nothing wrong with storing React components in the state but you could use React Children API and Children.toArray to transform and run some extra code for each child. Maybe even store them after you run Children.toArray.

Thank you.  I've added some code above.
